# JqGrid filter toolbar not refreshing on reload of grid

Tags: jqgrid

OK, I am having an issue with the filter toolbar retaining the filter values after clicking on the `Refresh` button at the bottom of the grid.

I have looked at numerous examples that do exactly that, `clear` the top filter toolbar fields to the default state (in the case of select list, to the first item in the list "Select..."), but I do not see any obvious difference between that code and mine

Values are being loaded into the filter toolbar drop down boxes via `JSON` request, and on selecting an item in the list the grid filters to the appropriate data.

The only thing that is not working is that the filter drop-down(s) do not clear the selected item upon clicking `refresh` grid.

Any ideas?

Not sure what code would help to post at this point, so I will post upon request

Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have answered my own question :)

The issue turned out to be related to naming convention for column names and indexes.

Example:

Before fix:

> { name: ClientId', index: 'ClientOrganization.Client.ClientId', width: '125', stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'], dataUrl: '@Url.Action("GetClientListForFilter")'} },

After fix:

> { name: 'ClientOrganization.Client.ClientId', index: 'ClientOrganization.Client.ClientId', width: '125', stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'], dataUrl: '@Url.Action("GetClientListForFilter")'} },

Basically the name needed to be the same as the index to properly refresh.  Not sure if this is expected behavior or not, but the fix works.  ;)

Justin